# SNMP Monitoring Juniper EX8216 switches for Rx/Tx power, temperature and bias current

Tags: snmp, monitoring, juniper-ex, juniper-mx

I am trying to monitor individual transceivers on two EX8216 Juniper switches regarding the following parameters:

> - RxPower
> - TxPower
> - Bias Current
> - Temperature

The methodology I am following is the following: I do an SNMP walk on the 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 (ifDescr) OID to view the switches' interfaces and I identify the indexes of the transceivers I am interested in. Having identified the correct indexes I use the Juniper [jnxDomCurrentTable](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/reference/general/jnxdomcurrententry-mib.html) MIB to identify the OID of the aforementioned parameters that I want to monitor. Namely, the OIDs I am using are the following:

```
 - jnxDomCurrentRxLaserPower :.1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.60.1.1.1.1.5.
 - jnxDomCurrentTxLaserBiasCurrent : .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.60.1.1.1.1.6.
 - jnxDomCurrentTxLaserOutputPower: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.60.1.1.1.1.7.
 - jnxDomCurrentModuleTemperature: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.60.1.1.1.1.8.
```

However, when I do SNMP GETs on the two EX8216 switches I do not retrieve any values, instead I receive a message that the OID does not exist: "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID".

The methodology I am following works fine for two MX960 Juniper devices and I am able to monitor the parameters mentioned above. However, it does not for the two EX8216 switches.

Thus my questions are:

1. Do EX8216 Juniper switches support the Juniper [Digital Optical
   Monitoring MIB](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/concept/mib-digital-optical-monitoring-overview.html)?
2. If they do support this MIB, do I have to do something further to
   enable SNMP polling of individual transceivers on the switches for
   the specific OIDs I mentioned above?
3. Finally, if they do not support it, is there another way to SNMP
   poll those switches for the parameters I am interested in?

I would be grateful for any pointers or advice on how to go about achieveing my goal.

Comment: Can you paste the output of "show chassis hardware detail" and "show version"?

Comment: SNMP is a big ole pile of crap, isn't it. See if the Juniper has something like Cisco's Enterprise Event Manager, or some type of syslog solution. Or, keep banging your head against SNMP. Are you sure you are not sending SNMP community strings (passwords) in clear text across your network?

Comment: SNMP is incredibly powerful with low overhead and extremely secure (when using v3).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the DOM MIB does not seem to be supported on any of the EX 22/32/42/82xx switches.  I've been bitten by this in the past.

The values are present on the device eg: `show interfaces diagnostics optics xe-1/1/0`, but not exported into the MIB tree.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the DOM MIB will only work with 10G XFP optical only, no support for 1G SFP yet unfortunately. See [Juniper MIB References](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/reference/mibs/mib-jnx-dom.txt)

Comment: Jaxxs thank you for your answer. You are correct that the DOM MIB is used for XFPs. Indeed the interfaces for which I can get values on the two MX960 Juniper routers are 10G XFPs. However, although the interfaces I want to monitor on the EX8216 switches are also 10G XFPs, I can't seem to get any values.

Comment: Are you using the XFP transceivers in an SFP+ line card? If so that could be the reason. The clock for the XFP is contained within the transceiver itself, and the clock for SFP+ moves it onto the line card.